# another meaning of 'with glasses'

Tags: meaning

> This suspect is an educated, middle class, nice Jewish lawyer ***with
>   glasses***,

Is there another meaning of 'with glasses'?
Or is the speaker just saying that without meaning?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it simply means that the suspect wore glasses. If it actually means something other than that, there's no way of telling without further context. (But I've never heard of any other meaning than exactly what you'd expect from the words themselves.)

Comment: There is no other context. So it's just 'glasses'! I thought there is another meaning of it. Thank you for commenting!

Comment: Perhaps they are implying stereotypes of glasses wearing populace (I would link but I can only find trashy spammy sites)